# "0 answers" indicators appear one pixel too high on the homepage

Tags: bug, design, homepage

On the homepage, for questions with no answers, the "0 answers" indicator is one pixel higher than the votes and views. This does not occur for answered questions:

[image]

To summarize the image:

- For the first two questions, the top line is just above the topmost pixel of the two outer numbers, and it overlaps with the top pixel of the middle zero. The bottom line is just below the bottom-most pixel of the two outer words, but you can see an extra row of pixels below "answers".
- For the third question, which has at least one answer, it looks fine: the guidelines I added line up perfectly.
- For the fourth question, the top line is just above the topmost pixel of the middle zero; notice the extra rows of pixels above the outer 0 and 19. The bottom line is just below the bottom-most pixel of "answers"; it overlaps with the bottom-most pixels of "votes" and "views".
- For the fifth question, both lines are placed just outside of the topmost and bottom-most pixels of the whole thing; the extra pixel rows are clearly visible.

One pixel may seem insignificant, but this screenshot was taken with 100% DPI; on high-DPI screens and when zoomed in, it looks more amplified and clearly off. That's how I was able to catch it.

These screenshots were taken in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Seems like if the *.narrow .status* class had a padding of 7px instead of 6px, it would fix it. I dislike hardcoded fixes, but it seems like quite a bit of the CSS has set pixel amounts =(.

Comment: related problem: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7856/36296